# How to merge two select query in single one

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following columns

```
StoreId,Date,Total,Type
```

There are two queries which are working as expected but I want to make one query which will do both the tasks. Please help

```
select lRetailStoreId,szDate,sum(dTaTotal) as GiftCardSales 
from TxSaleLineItem 
where szTypeCode='GIFT'
group by lRetailStoreID,szDate


select lRetailStoreId,szDate,sum(dTaTotal) as TotalSalesByDay 
from TxSaleLineItem 
group by lRetailStoreID,szDate
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select lRetailStoreId,
       szDate,
       sum(case when szTypeCode='GIFT' then dTaTotal else 0 end) as GiftCardSales,
       sum(dTaTotal) as TotalSalesByDay
from TxSaleLineItem
group by lRetailStoreID, szDate
```